# My php form works only partially and I dont know why

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have two froms on my page. With one I update or edit the data in first sql table. With second I can ad and delete the data in second sql table. Certain action is taken regarding the "ID" value.

This is my form:

```
<form class="form_hidden" name="form1" style="left:10px;top:10px;" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input class="final_form input_id"                  name="input_id"/>
    <input class="final_form input_date"                name="input_date" />
    <input class="final_form input_poczatkowy"          name="input_poczatkowy" />
    <input class="final_form input_gotowka"             name="input_gotowka" />
    <input class="final_form input_karta"               name="input_karta" />
    <input class="final_form input_pobrano"             name="input_pobrano" />
    <input class="final_form input_kto"                 name="input_kto" />
    <button class="hidden_button button_1" type="submit"  name="form1submit">btn</button>
</form>

<form class="form_hidden" name="form2" style="left:10px;top:300px;" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input class="final_form wydatek_id"                  name="wydatek_id"/>
    <input class="final_form wydatek_date"                name="wydatek_date" />
    <input class="final_form wydatek_kwota"               name="wydatek_kwota" />
    <input class="final_form wydatek_rodzaj"              name="wydatek_rodzaj" />
    <input class="final_form wydatek_opis"                name="wydatek_opis" />
    <button class="hidden_button button_1" type="submit" name="form2submit">btn</button>
</form>
```

And this is my php code:

```
$db_name = 'DATABASE_NAME';
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'DATABASE_USER';
$db_pass = 'PASSWORD';


$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name);

mysql_query("SET CHARSET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8` COLLATE `utf8_polish_ci`");   

if(isset($_POST['form1submit']))
{
    $raport_id = $_POST['input_id'];
    $raport_date = $_POST['input_date'];
    $raport_poczatkowy = $_POST['input_poczatkowy'];
    $raport_gotowka = $_POST['input_gotowka'];
    $raport_karta = $_POST['input_karta'];
    $raport_pobrano = $_POST['input_pobrano'];
    $raport_kto = $_POST['input_kto'];


   if($raport_id=='null'){
       $sql = "INSERT INTO `raporty`(`id`, `data`, `stan_poczatkowy`, `platnosci_gotowka`, `platnosci_karta`, `pobrano`,`kto_pobral`, `komentarz`)
           VALUES('".NULL."','".$raport_date."','".$raport_poczatkowy."','".$raport_gotowka."','".$raport_karta."','".$raport_pobrano."','".$raport_kto."','".NULL."')";
    }else{
        $sql = "UPDATE `raporty` SET  
            `data`='".$raport_date."', 
            `stan_poczatkowy`='".$raport_poczatkowy."', 
            `platnosci_gotowka`='".$raport_karta."', 
            `platnosci_karta`='".$raport_gotowka."', 
            `pobrano`='".$raport_pobrano."',
            `kto_pobral`='".$raport_kto."',
            `komentarz`='".NULL."'
             WHERE `raporty`.`id`='".$raport_id."'";
    }
    $retval = mysql_query($conn,$sql);
    header("Location: http:page");
    exit;               
}

if(isset($_POST['form2submit']))
{
    $wydatek_id = $_POST['wydatek_id'];
    $wydatek_date = $_POST['wydatek_date'];
    $wydatek_kwota = $_POST['wydatek_kwota'];
    $wydatek_rodzaj = $_POST['wydatek_rodzaj'];
    $wydatek_opis = $_POST['wydatek_opis'];

    if($wydatek_id=='null'){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `wydatki` (`id` ,`data` ,rodzaj` ,`kwota` ,`kategoria` ,`opis`) VALUES ('".NULL."','".$wydatek_date."','wydatek','".$wydatek_kwota."','".$wydatek_rodzaj."','".$wydatek_opis."')";      
    }else{
        $sql = "DELETE FROM `wydatki` WHERE `wydatki`.`id` = '".$wydatek_id."'";
    }
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    header("Location: http:page");
    exit;        
}
```

The fun fact is that only thing that work is the DELETE FROM enquiry for wydatki table. The rest just dont work, and I have no idea why. And, they worked BEFORE I added the second form.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are backwards in the first call to `mysql_query()`.

```
mysql_query($conn,$sql);
```

Should be:

```
mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

That being said, the `mysql_*` family of functions has been **deprecated** and should not be used in new code. Instead they have been replaced with `mysqli_*` and `PDO` with prepared statements.

---

It is also worth noting that your form is **completely** vulnerable to MySQL injection exploits from your [lack of any escaping of your database inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/). This is the precise reason why prepared statements exist in mysqli and PDO and why you should be using them. As it stands now anybody could erase your entire database by running their own SQL code through your form.

Comment: Ok, I made those changes and the first form works, although there is still problem with second. The DELETE FROM, works perfect, but creating the new record in `wydatki` still do not happen. Thanks for the advice about security though :)